# Error using postgres function "arr agg" in a knex query

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I am running into a problem when trying to run the following query. I am getting

```
missing FROM-clause entry for table \"s\"".
```

I have four tables here: `grants`, `users`, `regions`, and `states`.

- `grants` can have multiple rows per user
- `regions` can have multiple `states` per grant
- `states` is just id and state name

I am trying to get a nested "state" object so I don't get duplicated records when grants are available in multiple states. Regions table is `innerJoin` because there will always be a value matching the grants table: "state_wide" is a boolean.

```
return db("grants as G")
  .innerJoin("users AS U", "G.user_id", "U.id")
  .innerJoin("regions AS R", "G.id", "R.grant_id")
  .leftJoin("states AS S", "R.state_id", "=", "S.id")
  .select(
    "G.id",
    "G.grant_title",
    "G.grant_number",
    "G.grant_status",
    "G.grant_description",
    "G.grant_amount",
    "G.due_date",
    "U.first_name",
    "U.last_name",
    "U.email",
    "U.telephone",
    "U.department",
    "U.organization_name",
    "U.address_one",
    "U.address_two",
    "U.zip_code",
    "R.country_wide",
    "R.state_id",
    "R.county_id",
    db.raw("array_agg(S.state_name) AS state")
  )
  .groupBy("G.id", "G.grant_title");
```

Entire Error message

````
    "Message": "There was an error with your request",
    "Error": "select \"G\".\"id\", \"G\".\"grant_title\", \"G\".\"grant_number\", \"G\".\"grant_status\", \"G\".\"grant_description\", \"G\".\"grant_amount\", \"G\".\"due_date\", \"U\".\"first_name\", \"U\".\"last_name\", \"U\".\"email\", \"U\".\"telephone\", \"U\".\"department\", \"U\".\"organization_name\", \"U\".\"address_one\", \"U\".\"address_two\", \"U\".\"zip_code\", \"R\".\"country_wide\", \"R\".\"state_id\", \"R\".\"county_id\", ARRAY_AGG(S.state_name) as state from \"grants\" as \"G\" inner join \"users\" as \"U\" on \"G\".\"user_id\" = \"U\".\"id\" inner join \"regions\" as \"R\" on \"G\".\"id\" = \"R\".\"grant_id\" left join \"states\" as \"S\" on \"R\".\"state_id\" = \"S\".\"id\" - missing FROM-clause entry for table \"s\""
}```
````

Comment: Is there any other message or `DETAIL:` after the `missing From-clause entry for table "s"` error?  Can you paste the 2-3 lines before and after the error?

Comment: I don't know Knex, but the function is called `array_agg()` not `arr_agg()` in Postgres.

Comment: Aside from the misnamed function, as a_horse_with_no_name points out, it looks ok to me. Suggest drastically simplifying until you find the issue. It's slightly weird that your error has a lowercase `s`, but your table is aliased as `S`.

Comment: As @a_horse_with_no_name pointed out, the function was misnamed but I still get the same error. I edited the main post to add the full Error message

Comment: @Ernesto can you try lower-casing everything?  I haven't had time to tinker with this, but I wonder if `knex.js` is sending something in double-quoted uppercase.  FYI in Postgres, table name `U` is the same as table name `u` (everything gets lowercased), unless you specify it with double-quotes -- so table name `U` is **NOT** the same as table name `"U"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha. It took me awhile, but the issue is (as [richyen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12115778/richyen) intimated) the fact that you're using uppercase aliases. As I noted in the comments, it felt strange that the error used a lowercase 's'.

[Postgres is case-insensitive when it comes to keywords and unquoted identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

Normally, Knex surrounds your table names with double quotes, as you can see in your error message, so case is respected. However, it can't surround the alias in your `knex.raw` statement, because to Knex it's just a string. This leads Postgres to go looking for `s.state_name`, for which it is indeed missing a `FROM` clause.

You therefore need to either quote it yourself:

```
db.raw('array_agg("S".state_name) AS state')
```

or (much simpler) get into the habit of using lowercase aliases throughout!

Comment: Thank you all for the support. I actually fixed this yesterday by changing everything from uppercase to lowercase. The hint was the actual error pointing me to the lower case "s". from now on I will use lower case for aliases.